# How to use the Capacitor Browser API to access url in the browser

Tags: capacitor

```
I have a working code as such 
 this.paymentApiService.createPaymentMethod(paymentMethodDto)
            .subscribe((payment) => {
                    this.paymentForm = null;
                    if (payment.url) {
                        this.paymentForm = null;
                        console.log('Loading dismissed!');
                        loading.onDidDismiss();
                        const abcd = this.inAppBrowser.create(payment.url, '_blank');
                        abcd.on('loadstop').subscribe((event) => {
                            if (event.url.includes('/credit-card/wait')) {
                                abcd.close();
                                this.modalController.dismiss();
                                this.router.navigate(['credit-card/wait']);
                            } else if (event.url.includes('/credit-card/failure')) {
                                abcd.close();
                                this.modalController.dismiss();
                                this.router.navigate(['credit-card/failure']);
                            }
                        });
```

But recently the payment url provider has blocked inline access , so i am not able to use inApp browser to complete the process, so i decided to try Browser Api  from capacitor, but im not sure how to access the url through event handler
to be specific i want to do this

```
abcd.on('loadstop').subscribe((event) => {
                                if (event.url.includes('/credit-card/wait')) {
                                    abcd.close();
```

But using Browser api, im not able to access the event (finished is undefined)

```
 Browser.open({ url: payment.url });
```

Browser.addListener('browserFinished',(finished) =>  {
console.log("thisi is url at finish" +    finished )
})

```
     Browser.addListener('browserPageLoaded',(finished: any) =>  {
         console.log("thisi is url at page loaded" +    finished )
     })
```

Any suggestion how to check if the browser url is redirect to a specific point?

Comment: hey @valik, I'm currently at the same place. Could you tell what you did later on? did you find any workaround?

Comment: Hi @valik, Have you found any solution to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Capacitor's Browser plugin uses Safari View Controller on iOS and Chrome Custom Tabs on Android, none of those components provide the loaded url, so the plugin can't provide it neither.